# How to invoke Chrome extension with Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

Some Chrome APIs like `chrome.tabCapture.capture` require the extension to be invoked in order to work (i.e. user should click on the extension icon).

Is there a way to invoke the extension using Puppeteer (preferred) or in some other automated way?

Comment: You can use any automation tool that sends mouse clicks or keyboard events to invoke/active the extension using OS API instead of the internal debugging connection. So you simply open the extension page directly via its URL e.g. chrome-extension://blabla/popup.html then use your app's SendKeys to click the start button or whatever. I think I've seen an answer like that, try searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `--whitelisted-extension-id=<extension-id>` flag to Puppeteer.

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple extension-ids to the option?